# Derivative of $\int \limits _x^{x^2} f(t) dt$ with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$. Denote $$G(x) := \int \limits _x^{x^2} f(t) dt$$ Calculate $G'(x)$.
>   Check your expression for $G'$ works for $f(t) \equiv 1$

I've started with $G'(x) = 2xf({x^2}) - f(x)$ from differentiating the integral, but I'm not certain of where to go from here.

Comment: You forgot about the Chain Rule.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out; it was a transcription error.

Comment: So, what is $G(x)$ when $f(x)\equiv 1$?

Comment: That is, what is $\int_{x}^{x^2} 1\,dt$?

Comment: After the edit, I'm not quite sure I see what the OP is asking or where (s)he is stuck.

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry, I wasn't sure what end result I should be looking for. I now have an equality for $G'(x) = 2xf({x^2}) - f(x) = 2x - 1$. This satisfies the question, right?

Comment: Yes, IMO. You computed the general expression for $G^\prime$ in terms of $f$. You instantatied it (and verified) for the specific case of $f=1$. That is all that is asked.

Comment: Well, no, when $f(x)=1$, compute $G(x)$ exactly, then compute $G'(x)$ from there, then show that it agrees with $G'(x)=2xf(x^2)-f(x)$. @henbimsworth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$
$$G(x) = F(x^2)-F(x)$$
$$G'(x) = 2xf(x^2)-f(x)$$

If $f(x)=1, G(x) = \int_x^{x^2} f(x)dx = x^2-x$

So $G'(x) = 2x-1 = 2xf(x^2)-f(x)$

Comment: Sorry, I misread

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it's edited